# Bind Stringattribute to Column of separate Table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

is it possible to bind a String attribute of an JavaClass to a column of a different table.

**Example**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNTS")
public class Account {
    private Long id;
    private String nickname;
    private String address;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "A_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="A_NICKNAME")
    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }


    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

What would be the correct annotation if the address where a String in a separate table?

**Separate Table**

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Adresses` (
  `ad_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `ad_address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`da_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define address field of your object to be stored in another table (it has its own identifier that you don't have it in your account class ) but you can define another class for address and let it have its own mapping and table then your account class will have a many to one relationship with address class.This approach can have advantages too.What if you want to add another fields to your address table ? and if there's no chance that other fields can be added to your address table why do you want to store it in a separate table ?